# In Excel 2016, how do I insert a table row without fragmenting the conditional formatting?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

To duplicate a table row, I'm using this excellent bit of macro code (learned here) tied to a hotkey:

```
Public Sub InsRow()
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow    
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.ClearFormats ' suggested by RajeshS below
End Sub
```

But this fragments the conditional formatting (CF), as it inserts the formatting as well breaking up the CF "applies to" info. Before the insert, the CF looks like:

```
    Applies to: =$A$3:$U$100
```

After a new row is inserted at row 10 by the above macro, it becomes:

```
    Applies to: =$A$11:$U:$11
    Applies to: =$A$3:$U$10,$A$12:$U$101
```

How can I duplicate the formulas and values without fragmenting this conditional formatting?

Comment: You need this one to add to the code,
`ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.ClearFormats` @ row 4.

Comment: Thank you, @RajeshS. The macro still copies successfully, but the CF still gets fragmented at the inserted row.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32437215/1690180) you may find it helpful.

Comment: @KeithHowington, you have inserted the suggest Command line at wrong row, it should be after the row ,  ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow    coping the value. If you allow me I can edit the OP.

Comment: Your code should in this sequence,,                                                                            `Row1: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
Row 2: ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow                                            
Row 3: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.ClearFormats`

Comment: My mistake; it seemed "after the fact" and too late to prevent the fragmenting. I changed it in the macro; unfortunately the fragmenting effect is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wound up figuring it out. The following macro code (which I use all the time with Shift-Ctrl-Insert) adds rows even in tables without fragmenting the conditional formatting.

```
    Public Sub InsRow()
        Dim cellActive As Range
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False      ' Kill screen flicker
        Set cellActive = ActiveCell             ' Hold the entry cell for later
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert             ' Make the new row
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Copy  ' Grab the original row now up 1
        ' Handle earlier versions of Excel 
        If Application.Version => 16 Then
            ' xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats is defined as 14
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=14 ' 
        Else
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.PasteSpecial 
        End If
        Application.CutCopyMode = False         ' Release the selected row
        cellActive.Offset(-1, 0).Select         ' Pick the original cell position
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True       ' and release the screen
    End Sub
```

I've seen innumerable complaints about the CF format fragmentation, and could not find a solution that works. This appears to be it, and I certainly welcome suggestions and improvements.

(Later) One side benefit I just noted: Previous iterations of row duplication would have problems on the first row of a named range. It duplicated the row, but the new first row was actually outside of the range. In other implementations, it was the last row that needed to be avoided. This code seems to work fine on first and last rows.

(Later yet) Edited to add handling of Excel versions prior to Excel 2016. It now seems to work back to Excel 2007.

Comment: This does not work for me. Conditional Formatting rules get broken and multiplied after insertion anyways... I'm still looking for a way to fix this...?!